# How to sort a collection by its relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a  complicated filter for my hotels and in the end i have a collection that I want to sort the parent relations by its nested relationship so here I have as below :

```
  public function resultFilter($from_date, $to_date, $bed_count, $city_id, $stars, $type_id, $hits, $price, $accommodation_name, $is_recommended, $start_price, $end_price, $has_discount, $facility_id)
    {
//        $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
//            ->allowedFilters(['city_id','grade_stars','accommodation_type_id'])
//            ->allowedIncludes('gallery')
//            ->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
//                $q->with([
//                    'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($bed_count) {
//                        $q->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
//                    }
//                ]);
//            })
//            ->paginate(10);
//        ->get();
//            ->orderBy('hits','DESC')->paginate(10);
        $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationFacilities', 'gallery', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.discount', 'accommodationRoomsLimited', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
            $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
            $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
        }])->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
                $q->whereHas('accommodationRoomsLimited', function($query) use ($bed_count) {
                    $query->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
                });
        })->when($accommodation_name, function ($query, $accommodation_name) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', $accommodation_name);
        })->when($is_recommended, function ($query,$is_recommended){
            $query->where('is_recommended', $is_recommended);
        })->when($start_price, function ($query, $start_price) {
                $query->with([
                    'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($q) use ($start_price) {
                        $q->where('sales_price', '<', $start_price);
                    }
                ]);
            })->when($has_discount, function ($query, $has_discount) {
                $query->with([
                    'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($has_discount) {
                        $q->has('discount');
                    }
                ]);
            })
            ->whereIn('city_id', $city_id)
            ->whereIn('grade_stars', $stars)
            ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id', $type_id);
        if ($hits) { // or == 'blabla'
            $data = $data->orderBy('hits','DESC');
        } elseif ($price) { // == A-Z or Z-A for order asc,desc
            $f = $data->get();
            foreach ($f as $datas) {
                foreach ($datas->accommodationRoomsLimited as $g) {
                    dd($data);
                    $data = $data->accommodationRoomsLimited()->orderBy($g->roomPricingHistorySearch->sales_price);
                }
            }
        }
        $data = $data->paginate(10);
        return $data;
    }
```

So if you read code I added the sales_price that I want to sort my $data by it if the $price exists in the request. So in a short term question, I want to sort $data by sales_price in this query above.

**NOTE**
 : this filters may get more complicated so any other best practice or better way for that like spatie Query builder or local scopes would be appreciated although i tried both and yet they have their own limitation

Comment: If you are hitting limits, you can always use raw SQL...

Comment: What is the output so far are you getting ? What is the output of this query `$data = Accommodation::with(....` please print it.

Comment: In my opinion Laravel queries can become confusing/obfuscated pretty quickly when you're trying to perform complex operations. In stead of using ::with you can always use (leftJoin, join and rightJoin) to join the tables you need and orderBy the joined tables' column(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced that problem before. And it seems I need to explain a little about eager loading first.

You can't order by `eager loading`, you can order it after you fetch the data. Because
**eager load will split join query for better performance**. For example you querying `accomodation` and has relation with city. The `accomodation` table has 1000 records and the `city` table has 10.000 records. let's say the maximum id for eager loading is 250, the unique `city_id` from `accomodation` table is 780. There will be 5 query generated.

```
$data = Accomodation::with('city')->get();
```

1. `select * from accomodation`
2. `select * from city where id in [unique_id_1 - unique_id_250]`
3. `select * from city where id in [unique_id_251 - unique_id_500]`
4. `select * from city where id in [unique_id_501 - unique_id_750]`
5. `select * from city where id in [unique_id_751 - unique_id_780]`

Then laravel will do the job to create the relation by `city` query results. By this method you will fix `N+1` problem from join query, thus it's should be faster.

Then imagine you want to order `accomodation` by`city.name` with `with` method in query builder. let's take the 3rd query for example.

```
$data = Accomodation::with([
    'city' => function($q) { return $q->orderBy('name'); },
])->get();
```

the query will be:

`select * from city where id in [unique_id_251 - unique_id_500] order by name`

The city results will be ordered, but laravel will read it the same way. It'll create  `accomodation` first, then relate it with `city` queries. So the order from `city` won't affected `accomodation` order.

Then how to order it? I found out couple ways to achieve that.

1. Join query. this is the easiest way, but will make query slower. if your data isn't really big and the join query won't hurt your performance. Maybe 0.003 seconds better performance isn't really worth your 8 hours.
2. `sortBy` in collection function. You can sort it with a method from collection. 
   for example if you want to order the `accomodation` based on `country.name` from `city` relation, this script will help you.

```
$data = Accomodation::with('city.country')->get();
$data->sortBy(function($item) {
    return $item->city->country->name;
});
```

3. Flatten the collection. This method will try to flatten the collection so the results will be like `join` query then sorting it. You can use `map` method from collection. I do believe all the filters and searchable strings is should be included in data.

```
$data->map(function($item) {
    return [
      'city_name' => $city->name,
      ...
      all_searchable_data,
      all_shareable_data,
      ...
    ];
  })->sortBy('key1);
```

4. Change eager loading direction if possible. You can order it with changing base models. For example you use `city` instead `accomodation` to order it by `city.name`

```
$data = City::with('accomodation')->orderBy('name')->get();
```

And last, If your data rarely changes (example every 2 hours), You might thinking to use cache. You only need to invalidate the cache every 2 hours and create the new one. From my experiences, cache always faster than querying database if the data is big. You just need to know the interval or `event` to invalidate the cache.

Anything you choose is up to you. But please remember this, **when you processing bulk data with the collection from laravel, It could be slower than querying from the database. Maybe it's because PHP performance.**

For me the best way is using `eager loading` then `->map()` it then `cache` it. Why do I need to `map` it first before cache it? The reason is, by selecting some attribute will reduce the cache size. Then you'll be gain more performance by. And I can say it will produce more readable and beatiful code.

**Bonus**
this is how I doing this.

```
$data = Cache::remember("accomodation", 10, function() {
  $data = Accommodation::with([
    'city',
    ...
    ])
    ->get();

  return $data->map(function($item) {
    return [
      'city_name' => $item->city->name,
      ...
      all_additional_data,
      all_searchable_data,
      all_shareable_data,
      ...
    ];
  });
}

return $data->search(function($item) use ($searchKey, $searchAnnotiation, $searchValue) {
  switch ($searchAnnotiation) {
    case '>':
      return $item[$searchKey] > $searchValue;
      break;
    case '<':
      return $item[$searchKey] < $searchValue;
      break;
  }
})->sortBy($sortKey)->paginate();
```

The cache will save the processed data. thus the execution time needed is fetch data from cache, filter it, and sorting it. then transform it into paginate. you can set any additional cache in those flow for faster results.

`$data->paginate()` by create macro [`paginate`](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-laravel-collection) for `Collection`.

Comment: thanks for your complete answer it didnt solved my problem i gave you rep because i learned from it and there were no better answer and your effort worth the rep but here i have asked another 2 questions that i have now i ll be happy if you can help me out with those 2 i link below here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233264/how-to-calculate-and-append-a-variable-to-a-model-in-laravel

Comment: or here this one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200732/custom-sorting-by-nested-relationship-spatie-querybuilder