# How to calculate and append a variable to a model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Considering I have 3 models with relation `Hotel` `Room` and `Pricing` in my app, I need to show the cheapest room for each hotel.

I want to calculate the pricing and get the lowest price for a certain date which is today (for first step it would be the user chosen day later on) or any date for now ,and get the lowest price room among all and append that to the `hotel` model so later on I can use it in my `spatie` query builder package like below to be more clear of what i want to do i paste my spatie query builder below :

```
 $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
            ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','hotelRooms','hotelRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch'])
            ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::scope('bed_count'),
            AllowedFilter::scope('filter_price'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('city_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('is_recommended'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('accommodation_type_id'),
            'name',
            ])
            ->paginate(10);
        return $data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship set up to get hotel rooms (room belongs to hotel, hotel has many rooms), and a room has many pricings (depending on date):

```
$hotels = Hotel::all();

$cheapestRooms = [];

foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $roomIds = $hotel->rooms()->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $cheapestRoom[$hotel->name] = Room::whereIn('id', $roomIds)
        ->join('pricings', function ($join) {
            $join->on('room.id', '=', 'pricings.room_id')
                ->where('pricings.date', Carbon::now())
         })
        ->orderBy('room.price', 'asc')
        ->first();
}
```

This creates an associative array where the key is the hotel name and the value is the cheapest room.

To append that to your Hotel model, in Hotel.php I would do:

```
public function cheapestRoom($date) {
    $roomIds = $this->rooms()->pluck('id')->toArray();

    return = Room::whereIn('id', $roomIds)
        ->join('pricings', function ($join) {
            $join->on('room.id', '=', 'pricings.room_id')
                ->where('pricings.date', $date)
         })
        ->orderBy('room.price', 'asc')
        ->first();
}
```

And then you can use this like: `$hotel->cheapestRoom(Carbon::now);`

When you want a date range, you can modify the function to take 2 dates and use `whereBetween`.

Comment: well thanks but can i append that to my hotel model so for each hotel i always have my cheapest room appended to that mode?? thanks for your clear answer btw :)

Comment: Added a model function for you :) @Farshad

Comment: thanks man i try it and let you know the result i accepted the answer :)

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Try changing `Room::whereIn('id', $roomIds)` to `Room::whereIn('room.id', $roomIds)`  - it's probably because we're joining loads of tables and they all have the column 'id'